# I have an src folder with various classes , when I put these classes into different packages importing classes from each package doesn't work

Tags: java, class, package

I have an src folder with a number of classes. I have split these into 3 packages however now I get many cannot find symbol errors when I try and compile.

```
package game;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import exception.LineException;
```

This is an example of how I am trying to import the classes. For some reason even ArrayList is not imported.

Comment: Something is very wrong with your project setup if you cannot import basic Java packages.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Did you compile this with command line or build tool like maven,gradle or IDE?

Comment: I compiled this with the comand line and literally just added the classes in src to different folders with package names and add the above code at the top of the java file